# Images not lining up in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and can't seem to mkae my two bottom left and right images to line up with my middle image. The left and right images are shorter than the middle image. I have tried changing the bottom margin and padding but that doesn't cause any changes,

Here's the code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <img class = "small-img img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <img class = "btm-sml-img img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img class = "img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg"> 
                </div> 
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <img class = "small-img img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <img class = "btm-sml-img img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the 2 answers worked for me so I continued trying to figure out the best solution which was a really simple fix:

Simply the large image needed to be nested in another column. This gets everything perfectly inline and without any CSS.

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <img class = "small-img img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <img class = "btm-sml-img img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img class = "img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg"> 
                </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <img class = "small-img img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <img class = "btm-sml-img img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/cf/91/3a/cf913a709d54494598ff43a5aa844931.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a

```
<div class="container">
```

or

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

wrapping your rows, otherwise they're not going to work properly.

Comment: This is only a snippet of my entire page's code. I have a container set at the very begging of the code so this does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Not sure about `container-fluid`, but wrapping the code with the `container` div works quite well.  I know .container-fluid takes 100% of display for width, but the centering is off with that choice.  just `.container` works well